# How can I make "foreach" list items in alphabetical order

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking to list items (or in this case game titles) in alphabetical order.

using php I am getting games from a mysql databse, i use foreach to easly list all games, but i need it to list them in alphabetical order.

**games.php**

```
<table style="width:100%;" class="hover">
    <th style="width:5%;">A-Z</th>
    <th style="width:70%;">Games</th>
    <th style="width:10%;">Clans</th>
    <th style="width:10%;">Recruiting</th>


    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>None Specified</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
<?php 
    $query = " 
        SELECT 
            az,
            games,
            clans,
            recruiting
        FROM games 
    "; 

    try 
    { 
        // These two statements run the query against your database table.
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $stmt->execute(); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
        // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 

    // Finally, we can retrieve all of the found rows into an array using fetchAll 
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(); 
?> 


<?php foreach($rows as $row): ?> 
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['az']; ?></td>
        <td><a href="/games/"><?php echo $row['games']; ?></a></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['clans']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['recruiting']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>


<tr>
    <th style="width:5%;">A-Z</th>
    <th style="width:70%;">Games</th>
    <th style="width:10%;">Clans</th>
    <th style="width:10%;">Recruiting</th>  
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Instead of trying to coerce the loop to a different sort order, you should be applying `ORDER BY Games` to the SQL (or whichever column is the desired one to sort)

Comment: as other said in answers and comments, edit your SQL. But if for some reason you want to sort the DB results in different ways after getting it from db. Edit your question with that requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a ORDER in your query:

```
$query = " 
    SELECT 
        az,
        games,
        clans,
        recruiting
    FROM `games` 
    ORDER BY games ASC
";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your MySQL to

```
SELECT 
    az,
    games,
    clans,
    recruiting
FROM games 
ORDER BY games ASC
```